# How to configure Tilix to start with 4 splitted terminals by default

Tags: command-line

I want my Tilix to be started with 2 split on right and two splits on bottom.

I highly expected this to be available through preferences, but only found a command input. Then using
`tilix -a session-add-right` made a session creating-and-terminating loop which didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly, there indeed appears no direct way to indicate Tilix to always start with a certain configuration. You can achieve it in a somewhat more convoluted way. Key is to save a `.json` configuration file of your current session, then load Tilix with that session using the `--session` option.

Open Tilix, and open splits the way you want. Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the session. Specify a name for the `.json` configuration file. You could save the configuration file for example as .config/tilix-split. You can then open tilix with

```
tilix --session=~/.config/tilix-split.json
```

in the desired layout.

▶ To conveniently launch tilix this way in a terminal, you can create an alias:

```
alias tilix="tilix --session=~/.config/tilix-split.json"
```

▶ To launch it this way from a keyboard shortcut, specify the full command for the keyboard shortcut.

▶ To launch it this way from your application menu, you need to customize the launcher of Tilix:

- Copy the file `/usr/share/applications/com.gexperts.Tilix.desktop` to the folder `.local/share/applications` under your home folder.
- Edit the copy, and change the line that reads `Exec=tilix` to `Exec=tilix --session=~/.config/tilix-split.json`.

Comment: Comprehensive, thanks.

Comment: hey, your solution works, but for some reason I cant get the last method to work. It just launches as per normal when i click the icon. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the accepted answer:

I tried to create a custom launcher for Tilix, but the application wouldn't load the session that I provided in the launcher. After some research I found this issue:

https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix/issues/1016

Commenting out the line `DBusActivatable=true` fixed the problem and the session is now loaded correctly.